# Plot Projects - linking notification campaign to single geofence via API

Tags: android, ios, notifications, geolocation, geofencing

I'm using Plot Projects service to send geofencing notifications to users of iOS and Android application.

When creating a Campaign via the public API, I can link it to a Geofence by using the "Search" field, as per https://admin.plotprojects.com/docs/api/v1. However, if two or more Geofences would match the search term, all of them would be linked to that Campaign.

When looking at the Plot Projects Dashboard, I see that option under Geofences tab, saying "Select existing Geofence", where I can link the Notification campaign to a single geofence. This is exactly what I'd need, but seem to not be able to find it in the API.

Is there a way to do this via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently campaigns have a non-documented `regionIds` property you could use to specify which geofences should be part of a campaign. You can set this property with an array containing the ids of the geofences. When specifying this property, you must omit the `search` property.

This `regionIds` field is available for GET, POST and PATCH requests.